# How to write public module in KOA?

Tags: javascript, koa

I'd like to make a public module used by many controllers,I've written like this:

```
//module.js
export.node = function(that){
 return co(function*(){
  .....
    var data = {
      name:"xx"
    };
     return data;
 })
}

//controller.js
var dataUtil = require('../module');
var _data = dataUtil(this);
```

Is there another solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wrap your generator in `co`; you can simply bring it in with `yield *`, so:

```
// utils/node.js
exports.node = function *(that) {
    var bar = yield someAsyncThing();
    that.body = { bar: bar };
}
```

Then to call it

```
var node = require('./utils/node').node;
api.get = function *() {
    yield *node(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `yield` can synchronous method to using asynchronous function.
    `exports.node = function *getData(){
         var data = 'xxxxx';
         return data;
      }`

```
`var node = require('').node;
 var data = yield node()`
```